# limit(1).skip(1) : Why does it return second document and not nothing?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongodb so, please bear with me. I googled this but could not find a convincing answer.
I understand the following should limit n1 documents in the result and skip n2 of that.

```
>db.mycol.find({},{"title":1}).limit(n1).skip(n2)
```

Why should the following query return the second document in the collection? Should it not return nothing ? ( Limit one gives the first document and skipping that leaves us with nothing ).

```
>db.mycol.find({},{"title":1}).limit(1).skip(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to do when you put `limit` before `skip`?

If you limit `N` elements and then skip `K`

this is logically equivalent to skip `K` and limit `N-K`.

I suppose the optimizer knows this as well and expect you too as well.

See [pipeline optimization](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#skip-limit-sequence-optimization)

Comment: I was just playing around with the commands but this is interesting, Thank you !

Comment: This should also mean that limit(1).skip(1) becomes skip(1).limit(0) right ?

Comment: I doubt that, according to the specs it won't change.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the following should limit n1 documents in the result and skip n2 **of that**.

Nope, you got that wrong. Here is what happens:

1. Your query is processed by the query optimizer, which puts `.sort()`, `.skip()` and `.limit()` into ***exactly*** this order
2. The documents to be returned are identified, either by means of utilizing indices or a collection scan
3. Now they are sorted according to the parameters of the `.sort()` clause, if present
4. The first number of documents of that sorted list of documents are skipped according to the parameter of the `.skip()` clause.
5. Now, a number of documents equalling the parameter of the `.limit()` clause are returned

Actually it is easy to prove:

```js
> db.bg.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.bg.insert({a:2})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.bg.insert({a:3})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.bg.insert({a:4})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.bg.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56889a8a32a39e5b2c96acb5"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56889a8d32a39e5b2c96acb6"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56889a9032a39e5b2c96acb7"), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56889ad332a39e5b2c96acb8"), "a" : 4 }

// According to your logic, this query would be empty
// (Only one doc returned, and of that returned one skipped)
// But it bears a result…
> db.bg.find().sort({a:-1}).limit(1).skip(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56889a9032a39e5b2c96acb7"), "a" : 3 }

// …actually the same result when switching the place of the clauses
> db.bg.find().sort({a:-1}).skip(1).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56889a9032a39e5b2c96acb7"), "a" : 3 }

// Even when we put the sort clause to the end.
// If the query optimizer would not have enforced the order mentioned
// we would have natural order as in the default query,
// then skip 1 (we would be at {a:2}),and limit to that document, making
// the sort clause useless.
// But, as you can see, it is the same result as before
> db.bg.find().skip(1).limit(1).sort({a:-1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56889a9032a39e5b2c96acb7"), "a" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.skip/

```
NOTE
You must apply cursor.skip() to the cursor before retrieving any documents from the database.
```

Whereas limit is applied while querying results.

So find finds all the documents which match criteria and Skip is applied before retrieving documents and number of documents given in limit are retrieved.